# How to have a file stream as a class member

Tags: c++, io, stream, iostream

I have the following parser class that works in Visual C++

```
class Parser
{
   private:
   const char* filename;
   std::ifstream filestream;
   std::vector<std::string> tokens;
   unsigned int linect;

   public:
   Parser(const char* filename);
   bool readline();
   std::string getstrtoken(unsigned int i) const { return tokens[i]; }
   int getinttoken(unsigned int i) const { return atoi(tokens[i].c_str()); }
};

Parser::Parser(const char* filename) :
   filename(filename),
   linect(0)
{
   filestream = ifstream(filename); // OK in VC++, not with GCC?
}

bool Parser::readline()
{
   std::string line;
   getline(filestream, line);
   std::stringstream ss(line);
   std::string token;

   tokens.clear();
   while(getline(ss, token, ' ')){ if(token != "") tokens.push_back(token); }
   linect++;
   return (filestream != NULL);
}
```

But when I try to compile it with GCC 4.8.2, I get errors saying that I cannot assign to `filestream`. From what I read elsewhere on this site, you can do

```
std::ifstream filestream(filename);
```

but you cannot do

```
std::ifstream filestream;
filestream = ifstream(filename);
```

which is essentially what I need to do if I want to declare `filestream` as a member of the `Parser` class and initialize it in the constructor.

I would like to have the file stream kept within the `Parser` class so that those who use the parser don't need to declare and keep track of it. It seems to me that this should be self-contained in the `Parser` class since its internal methods (e.g. `readline()`) are the only ones that use it.

Is there a way to achieve this that works with both platforms?

Thanks.

**edit:** My fix was to explicitly call the `open()` method of `ifstream`. My parser class constructor now looks like:

```
Parser::Parser(const char* filename) :
   filename(filename),
   linect(0)
{
   filestream.open(filename);
   // Do some checking to make sure the file exists, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, since `std::ifstream` has deleted copy constructor and copy assignment. You may get around by doing

```
filestream.swap(ifstream(filename)).
```

The fact that it compiles on visual studio is mostly because it gets inlined into either move assignment or move constructor(I'm not so good to tell you which exactly). If you try

```
std::ifstream myF;
filestream = myF;
```

it won't compile.

However you may try to do the move I wrote, or you can just call `.open`(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open)

Comment: I just added `filestream.open(filename)` to the body of the `Parser` constructor. I forgot that you could open a file outside of the stream's constructor... doh!

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution would be for you to:

1. Construct a `ifstream` first.
2. Construct a `Parser` using the `ifstream` object.
3. Change `Parser` to store a reference to an `istream` object. This allows you the flexibility of being able parse the contents of a file, stdin, and a string.

---

```
class Parser
{
   private:
      std::istream& str;
      std::vector<std::string> tokens;
      unsigned int linect;

   public:
      Parser(std::istream& s) : str(s) ... {}

      ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**std::ifstream** don't have a copy constructor, probably one of the many extensions of VC++. Correct code is:

```
Parser::Parser(const char* filename) :
   filename(filename),
   linect(0),
   filestream(filename)
{
}
```

Please take note of member variable and parameter **filename**. Use **this->** or change name (recommended, normally prefix is used for member variables `_` or `m_`)

Comment: what if string is defined before the fstream? wont that potentionally let `filestream` empty, since the member variables are constructed in their order of declaration(afaik)?

Comment: Interesting, albeit a bit confusing. I will go with the other option.

Comment: in inline initialization i tried to use always parameters variables to avoid this type of errors, by yes, member variables are initialized in the same order as they are declared, not in the order used in inline initialization, GCC with option -Wall warn about this. The problem in this case is that **member name == parameter name**